# Application icons missing from Cinnamon panel when running as root

Tags: root, cinnamon, icons

I've written a little application and added its icons to `/usr/share/icons/`
path. I use Cinnamon desktop.

When I run the application the desired icon appears correctly in the panel.  But if I run it as root the default applications icon appears instead of it.

I've double checked that the icons have 777 privileges.

Comment: General advice: don't log in as root.

Comment: my application needs root privilege and the error occurs if i just run it with gksu or a root session

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: I thought I had a similar problem but it turned out that while the desktop file supplies the desktop icon, the window list icon comes from the app itself. Setting the icon property on the GTK application window fixed the problem for me.